# Kotlin multiplatform JVM type mismatch in IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a project which contains the following modules:

- common
- common-js
- common-jvm
- backend
- web

The idea is that I put my shared (kotlin) code (mainly models) in common, which can be used in both the kotlin driven backend and the javascript driven webapp using the recently introduced multiplatform support. To do this, I created a new multiplatform application in Intellij, and added the backend and web modules to it.

An example class in the common module:

```kotlin
data class Show(
    val id: Long,
    val type: ShowType,
    val title: String,
    var description: String? = null
)
```

The backend is a simple spring boot application. It has a dependency on the common-jvm project:

```gradle
compile project(":common-jvm")
```

Now when I run `gradle bootRun`, the application starts and works fine. However, when I try to run the same application using IntelliJ, I get errors like:

> Error:(68, 26) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is `kotlin.Long` but `java.lang.Long` was expected
>   Error:(68, 65) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is `kotlin.String!` but `java.lang.String` was expected

On this line, I try to create an instance of the `Show` model using data from a json source:

```
val movie = Show(json.get(id).asLong(), ShowType.MOVIE, json.get(movieTitle).asText())
```

I am using Kotlin 1.2.10 and spring boot 1.5.9.RELEASE.

Anybody who knows what causes this and how it can be solved? I tried putting `-Xmulti-platform` in the additional command line parameters in the project structures for the backend module, but this did not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delegate build/run actions to Gradle, since building multiplatform projects with IDEA is not supported at this moment.

[image: Build > Build Tools > Gradle > Runner]

Comment: That is indeed what I resolved to in the end, and it fixes it. Thanks! Now lets hope that support is added soon :)

Comment: Anything similar for maven?

Comment: @Manish, multiplatform projects are not currently supported in Maven to start with, but if you're just looking for something like "Delegate IDE build/run actions to maven" it can be found in "Build tools > Maven > Runner" settings page in the recent versions of IDEA.