# Unable to build corda-training-solutions and corda-training-template projects in IntelliJ

Tags: corda

When I try to build the corda-training-solutions or corda-training-template projects in IntelliJ I get errors like:

Error:(25, 8) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: java
Error:(38, 2) Kotlin: Cannot access class 'java.lang.String'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Error:(38, 7) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.String but java.lang.String was expected

For project files that contain import java.util there is an unresolved reference error.

Tried deleting and re-downloading projects and rebuilding projects.  I have jdk 1.8.0_221 installed and referenced in Gradel Build, Execution, Deployment settings.

import java.util.Currency    Unresolved reference: java
@Path("iou")                 Cannot access class java.lang.String

Comment: Did you choose `open the project` rather than `import it` into IntellJ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij issue resolving dependency for spring kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697594/intellij-issue-resolving-dependency-for-spring-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you had run into might be a building issue that is caused by IntelliJ. We had came across a couple of incidences where class reference is not properly imported in IntelliJ. And, it does not run the CorDapp via terminal or anything.

A quick fix is simply re-clone the project at a different directory and open the project. We are do so to let IntelliJ to re-build the project and generate the .idea folders from scratch.

Lastly, we had already deprecated the training-solutions and training-template repositories. The CorDapp that is demoed there is re-located to: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp